# Change Position of WooCommerce Notification on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Change position of Woocommerce Notification is working but after update the woocommerce on Version 3.3.3 it's not working.

> /includes/wp-notice-functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_before_product_cat_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
```

Removed these 3 functions. i just copied these 3 actions from above file mention then remove these actions using my function file

```
<div class="center">Your Order</div>

<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
```

from-checkout.php printing notices under the title, but it's always display above the title.

Can anyone please explain me where i'm doing mistake.

Comment: Where do you want the notice to appear?

Comment: <div class="center">Your Order</div>
under this tag

Comment: Super weird, you can't move it regardless of what I do...  Might be a core bug.

Comment: i think so, i've search complete in plugin directory, i get only one more place but that's not in any action or filter just calling function, disable that also but still issue not resolved

Comment: I even tried commenting out all the references to wc_print_notices() in the template files but it still output the notices in the same spot!  I'd raise this as a core bug.

Comment: Thanks, Where you rise the issue, can you please send me link here

Comment: I've added a work around solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a workaround.  I noticed that it's actually an AJAX request that is calling a function called `update_order_review` which is printing the notices via `wc_print_notices`.  You can hook into the trigger `updated_checkout` to move the notices further down the page using some jQuery.  Place the following jQuery into a file called es-checkout.js in a subdirectory js.

```
(function($){
    'use strict';

    $(function(){
        var $orderReview = $("#order_review_heading");

        $( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function( event, data  ) {
            console.log( 'checkout was updated' );
            console.log(data);
            $( '.woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-message' ).remove();
            $orderReview.append(data.messages);

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $orderReview.offset().top
            }, 500);
        });
    })
})( jQuery );
```

Enqueue the script with this code, notice it has dependencies on WooCommerce scripts.

```
function es_checkout_scripts() {
    if( is_checkout() )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'es-checkout', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/es-checkout.js', array('jquery', 'wc-checkout'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'es_checkout_scripts' );
```

Comment: via jquery, it's not working, i tried that code, but after load page, we removed the notice then re add, i don't think the notice load via Ajax because when i update the cart on checkout page, it's reload the page and then notice on page

Comment: @ImranSaleem It's adding a notice via AJAX that's why you can't remove it via a hook. Works fine for me on the default WordPress theme. Up to you now to work out what the difference is but it's not a WooCommerce bug.  Good luck :)